# When installing SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2008 R2 what Windows Server Roles, if any, are required?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

The server(s) I was provided to install SQL 2012 on already has/have the Application Server and Web Server (IIS) Roles enabled.

The OS as mentioned above is Windows Server 2008 R2 w/ up to date SP/Patch.

In the interest of best practices / security / lowest surface area I am wondering if these roles should be enabled or not.

After searching the internet as much as reasonably possible and successfully running the System Configuration Checker tool on a server with no roles installed - I have come to the belief other than the .NET 3.5 requirement for installation (covered in Windows features as far as I can tell) nothing else is required with the only exception being the IIS role for SSRS installations in some cases.

I just cannot find anything definitive from which to make a recommendation on leaving the roles as is or removing them.

Here is one resource I looked through extensively when trying to figure this out - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500469.aspx

Thoughts, experiences, and/or references are appreciated.

FYI - I posed the question w/ a link out on the #sqlhelp tag on Twitter and got a response from Denny Cherry that the answer is "none".  (Thanks Denny!)

Comment: This should be on Database Administrators SE. (http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I will do that in the future.  Thanks - I wasn't aware of all the different sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posed this question w/ a link out on the #sqlhelp tag on Twitter and got a response from [MrDenny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4197/mrdenny) that the answer is "none". (Thanks MrDenny!)